# new Date () javascript not showing correct date in Pacific timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-format

Below code works differently in different timezone/location.

In India at my desk it works perfectly

```
var sdate =  new Date("2013-12-12");
document.write(sdate)
```

shows as below

Thu Dec 12 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

which is correct.

However when same code when I host to my client's server in USA it shows as below

Wed Dec 11 2013 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

What to do to show date correctly in Client's host?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Define 'correctly'. Right now it shows the local representation of the same period in time (shifted as timezone dictates). If what you want is the local 'start-of-date' point, use `new Date('2013/12/12 00:00:00')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does currently not have a built-in standard object that represents a date without a time.  When you use the `Date` object, despite its name you should think of it as a "date and time" object, closer to what other languages call `DateTime`.  There is always an implied time component, even you don't provide one.

The constructor of the `Date` object has several different forms that vary by the arguments you pass in.  If you pass a string, it will try to parse that string.  However, the effects can vary depending on what that string contains, and can vary across implementations.

For example:

```
// This will be parsed as UTC at midnight (but doesn't work in IE8)
new Date("2013-05-31")

// This will be parsed as local time in Chrome, and cause "Invalid Date" in IE
new Date("2013-05-31 00:00:00")

// This will be parsed as local time at midnight, and usually works in all browsers, but is not standardized.
new Date("2013/05/31")
```

That last one might be acceptable, but it still seems fishy to me.  Most people don't use that format, they are more likely to enter mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy, which can lead to ambiguity depending on culture and the date you enter.

You are probably better off passing numeric arguments to the `Date` constructor:

```
new Date(2013, 4, 31)
```

Note that when you do this, the months run 0-11 instead of 1-12.  Because I passed a `4`, this represents the month of May.  This is a common source of error, so watch it carefully.

I should also mention that you can eliminate all of the browser variations and support any format you want, if you use a library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com).  For example:

```
// This will be parsed as local time
moment('2013-05-31','YYYY-MM-DD')

// This will be parsed as UTC
moment.utc('2013-05-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

There are many other good date/time libraries as well.  If you need to support older browsers, then Moment is a good choice.  But if you're supporting mostly modern browsers, then try [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) instead.

Comment: @RobG - Thanks.  Old answer, I updated for correct terminology.